# ionic2 TypeScript shows error: Cannot find name 'google' and '$', but google map and jquery still works

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, angular

I am trying to build a ionic2 application using TypeScript.

In index.html, I've tried to plug the jquery and google map JS API into it before cordova.js:

```
  <!-- Vendor -->
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=XXXXX&signed_in=false"></script>
  <script src="asset/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <!-- cordova.js required for cordova apps -->
  <script src="cordova.js"></script>
```

The google map and jquery inside the app is working normally, however just wondering why these error messages shows when I run "ionic serve" command

```
TypeScript error: /Users/xxx/client_app/app/pages/step1/step1.ts(15,21): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
TypeScript error: /Users/xxx/client_app/app/pages/step1/step1.ts(30,18): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
TypeScript error: /Users/xxx/client_app/app/pages/step1/step1.ts(37,24): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'google'.
TypeScript error: /Users/xxx/client_app/app/pages/step1/step1.ts(39,5): Error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
TypeScript error: /Users/xxx/client_app/app/pages/step1/step1.ts(39,42): Error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
TypeScript error: /Users/xxx/client_app/app/pages/step1/step1.ts(39,76): Error TS2304: Cannot find name '$'.
```

Here are part of my code in step1.ts:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.gmap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gmap_canvas'), {
            center: {
                lat: 22.280102,
                lng: 114.183751
            },
            zoom: 16,
            streetViewControl: false,
            styles : [{
                featureType: "poi",
                elementType: "labels",
                stylers: [
                    { visibility: "off" }
                ]
            }],
            mapTypeControlOptions: {
                mapTypeIds: [google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP]
            },
            overviewMapControl: false,
            mapTypeControl: false,
        });

    this.gmap.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(document.getElementById('gmep_center_marker'));

    $('#gmep_center_marker').css({ top: ($('#gmap_canvas').height() / 2) - $('#gmep_center_marker').height() });
  }
```

Comment: you need addtional type description files

Comment: Btw this happens and is required because typescript completely isolates your app from the rest of the world.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The easy fix is to add variable declarations on top of your file:

```js
import {...} from '...';

declare var google: any;
declare var $: any;
```

I'd suggest to install the proper type definition files though. I know there is one for JQuery that you install like this:

```
typings install jquery --ambient --save
```

And in your component file at the top add this:

```js
///<reference path="../typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts"/>

import {...} from '...';
```

I don't know of a typings file for the google api, so you might as well use the quick fix mentioned above just for using google.

Comment: This simple solution works, thanks rinukkusu :)

While looking into the jquery typescript def file, wondering why type script making simple tool that complicated?  https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery/jquery.d.ts

Comment: I am getting same issue using InfoBox. It shows cannot find name InfoBox at this line:    var ib = new InfoBox(myOptions);