# Cannot find name 'swal' ng2

Tags: angular, typescript, sweetalert

I am using angular 2 with typescript 1.6 and when i compile the code i get this errors:

> Cannot find name 'swal' ng2

This is the code:

```
 
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
```

@Component({
    selector: 'message-list',
    styles: [],
    template: require('./message-list.component.html')
})

export class MessagesComponent {
    ngOnInit(): void {
        swal({ title: "Error!",   text: "Here's my error message!",   type: "error",   confirmButtonText: "Cool" });
    }
}

Comment: I have run npm install sweetalert --save also and checked swal on console chrome, it work find. But when I use swal function on Component, it through the error ```Cannot find name 'swal' ng2```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank everyone first, i have just found solution on this link 
[ionic2 TypeScript shows error: Cannot find name 'google' and '$', but google map and jquery still works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37941683/ionic2-typescript-shows-error-cannot-find-name-google-and-but-google-map)

The easy fix is to add variable declarations on top of your file:

```
    import {...} from '...';

    declare let swal: any;
```

Comment: @ThomasDuc that was the fastest solution available, thanks a lot. Can you please explain how it works.